# Flutter iOS error: GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m: fatal error: module 'package_info' not found

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods

In my Flutter project, I target both Android and iOS, and I added the following libraries in my `pubspec.yaml`file:

```
  url_launcher: ^5.7.10
  package_info: ^0.4.3+4
```

Now, when I run my app in debug mode on an iOS emulator, I got the following error during compile time:

```
/Users/blabla/MyProject/Developpement/myproject/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:10:9: fatal error: module 'package_info' not found
    @import package_info;
     ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
```

I can see the error in Xcode, when I open `GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m`:

[image: Error in Xcode]

I took a look at [that](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/53573), and maybe the problem comes from the fact that I use a custom Cocoapods file in my project (a custom `Podfile`), not sure though. The problem is: I need that file to import AWS libraries in my iOS project.

Here is the content of my `Podfile`:

```
platform :ios, '12.0'

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'AWSMobileClient'
  pod 'AWSAPIGateway'
  pod 'AWSS3'
end
```

So how can I fix that problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to make this work by doing the following:

1. create a new Flutter project, and add, in `pubspec.yaml`, the `url_launcher` and `package_info` libraries
2. open the iOS module using Xcode, and open the `Podfile`
3. copy the content of that `Podfile`, and paste it in the `Podfile` of my current project
4. move, in the `target Runner` block of my `Podfile` project, the already existing libraries (in my case, the 3 AWS libraries)